# How to use Ag-Grid with row-wise formatting (effectively a transposed Ag-Grid table)?

Tags: ag-grid

I am looking to use AgGrid to display some time ordered data - however, for aesthetic reasons I want each entry to be a new column.

I envision this as making a nice AgGrid table and then transposing it (ie. what would usually be rows becomes columns)

I'm finding it difficult to set cellRenderers / valueFormatters / cellStyles row-wise; any ideas on how I could do this?